# Configuring SSL with tomcat

Tags: tomcat, ssl

a very good day to all .

I have Generating a self signed  KeyStore file and added it to Tomcat using this

```
<Connector port=”8443″
maxThreads=”150″ minSpareThreads=”25″ maxSpareThreads=”75″
enableLookups=”true” disableUploadTimeout=”true”
acceptCount=”100″ debug=”0″ scheme=”https” secure=”true”
clientAuth=”false” sslProtocol=”TLS”
keystoreFile=”/webapps/techtracer.bin”
keystorePass=”ttadmin” />
```

Actually my link to access an Application running inside
a Tomcat is using this

```
http:localhost:8080/SpringEx/index.html
```

But the ssl certicate  works only if i do this

```
http:localhost:8443/SpringEx/index.html
```

Is this behaviour normal ??

Thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is normal. However if you want to access using a more friendly link like `https://localhost/SpringEx/index.html` try this:

You probably have another connector in your `server.xml`

```
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
    port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Try and set the redirectPort to 443, and then use 443 as port in your connector too.

```
<Connector port=”443″
    maxThreads=”150″ minSpareThreads=”25″ maxSpareThreads=”75″
    enableLookups=”true” disableUploadTimeout=”true”
    acceptCount=”100″ debug=”0″ scheme=”https” secure=”true”
    clientAuth=”false” sslProtocol=”TLS”
    keystoreFile=”/webapps/techtracer.bin”
    keystorePass=”ttadmin” />
```

Now you should be able to access your service on `https://localhost/SpringEx/index.html`